# Why does wget keep fetching recursively despite -l5?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to mirror a website with `wget`. It works out just fine until a strange thing occurs.

I'm using this line:

```
wget -e robots=off --wait 1 -l5 --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent --no-clobber -x -nH http://www.site.info/city
```

On the front page there is a "Om"-link (that's swedish for "About"). This is like a banner that will follow any page throughout the website. So if I stand on the front page `www.site.info/city` and click on "Om" I will be linked to `www.site.info/city/om` where of course an opportunity to click "Om" is present at the banner.

However, `wget` will continue to follow that "Om"-link on every single page (even though I only want it to be done on the first occurance). Eventually it will look like this:

> http://www.site.info/city/om/nu/132-walk-of-fame/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/om/newsmail

Återanvänder befintlig anslutning till www.site.info:80.

How on earth do I stop/change this behaviour of `wget`?

Comment: Try option `--max-redirect`.

Comment: Try excluding the dir with `-X om` or the url with `--reject-regex '/om/om/' --regex-type pcre`.